# VQGAN + Clip Colab Pro: Could not resolve host: mirror.io.community

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am having issues with VQGAN + clip. I subscribed to Colab Pro. When I select the execute button for "Selección de modelos a descargar”, I receive a notice that says
"Could not resolve host: mirror.io.community”   Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The notebook has been updated with the latest model links.

You can find the latest version within the README.md of the [official GitHub Repo](https://github.com/justinjohn0306/VQGAN-CLIP)